# What is sys._MEIPASS in Python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

What is sys._MEIPASS. What is the value of this variable and it's use ? I was a looking one python script but when I ran it on eclipse(pydev). It showing error.

Answer (score 33):

sys._MEIPASS is a temporary folder for PyInstaller. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile) for more information.

Answer (score 10):

This is the path attribution created by pyinstaller, it is quite useful when you have some resource files (like .bmp .png) to load in your python one-file-bundled app.

> When a bundled app starts up, the bootloader sets the `sys.frozen`
> attribute and stores the absolute path to the bundle folder in
> `sys._MEIPASS`. For a one-folder bundle, this is the path to that
> folder. For a one-file bundle, this is the path to the temporary
> folder created by the bootloader.

a typical use would be:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    bundle_dir = Path(sys._MEIPASS)
else:
    bundle_dir = Path(__file__).parent

path_to_dat = Path.cwd() / bundle_dir / "other-file.dat"
```

You may want to check details here:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the error Lint gives you in your editor (Eclipse, MS-Code, ...) add the following comment at end of your line:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False): # Running as compiled
        running_dir = sys._MEIPASS + "/files/" # pylint: disable=no-member
```

The [solution was from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562085/1431079) if you want to disable a single line of code, not all errors of a kind.

Comment: `# pylint: disable=protected-access` for me with Pylint 2.15.7