# Is it reasonable to use type(a) as a dictionary key?

Tags: python, dictionary, pygments

I am trying to store files in a dictionary depending on their type. For this, I am using `pygments` API as follow:

```python
# Initialization of the self.files dictionary
self.files = dict()
# Scanning and categorizing the files
for file in files:
    lexer = guess_lexer__for_filename(file, None)
    if type(lexer) in self.files:
        self.files[type(lexer)].append(file)
    else:
        self.files[type(lexer)] = [file]
```

But, now, when passing this code through `pylint3`, I get a warning telling me that I should use `isinstance()` in place of `type()` (unidiomatic-typecheck).

The best way to workaround this warning I found so far is as follow:

```python
self.files = dict()
for file in files:
    lexer = guess_lexer__for_filename(file, None)
    if lexer.__class__ in self.files:
        self.files[lexer.__class__].append(file)
    else:
        self.files[lexer.__class__] = [file]
```

But, does it really solve the problem ? And, moreover, I started to doubt that using a type as a key in a dictionary is robust enough.

So, is there more suitable and robust ways to do? Any solution with good arguments is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `type()` output, an object, as a key is just fine. [Ignore that warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829236/is-it-possible-to-ignore-one-single-specific-line-with-pylint) in this case.

I'd use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) or [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to extend the list value:

```
self.files = {}

for file in files:
    lexer = guess_lexer__for_filename(file, None)
    self.files.setdefault(type(lexer), []).append(file)
```

or

```
from collections import defaultdict

self.files = defaultdict(list)

for file in files:
    lexer = guess_lexer__for_filename(file, None)
    self.files[type(lexer)].append(file)
```

However, on Python 3, you could investigate if [`functools.singledispatch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) could be used to handle your use-case instead. It calls a registered function for a given object type, taken from the first argument, and supports subclasses.

Comment: The `singledispatch()` is nice but it is not fitting the usage I intend to have. And, I did not know the `setdefault`/`defaultdict` trick and I will definitely use it. Thanks a lot !