# How to deal with Pylint unused import message on submodule?

Tags: python, pylint

I have this code:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg  # Short name cause pyqtgraph is looong
import pyqtgraph.exporters

# ... some code

pg.foo()
pg.exporters.ExportItem(blah)
```

Now pylint complains about the `import pyqtgraph.exporters` saying it is unused import. What is the Pythonic or elegant solution to fix this warning?

Note that without having `import pyqtgraph.exporters`, the methods in that submodule cannot be called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to ignore one single specific line with pylint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829236/is-it-possible-to-ignore-one-single-specific-line-with-pylint)

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like that:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg  # Short name cause pyqtgraph is looong
import pyqtgraph.exporters  # pylint: disable=unused-import

# ... some code

pg.foo()
pg.exporters.ExportItem(blah)
```

To prevent pylint warnings.