# VS Code: Tell pylint to ignore the next line?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Looking for a way to tell pylint to ignore the error on the next line. The method for JavaScript is given [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript), just

```
// @ts-ignore
```

I tried some logical variants of that for Python, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `# pylint: disable=fixme, line-too-long`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562085/7049436) StackOverflow answer.