# How to have the linter ignore ascii art

Tags: pylint

I'm using vscode and pylint and it's flagging my file header ascii art as a possible problem. Is there a way to ignore just the file docstring, ascii art, or something... Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to ignore one single specific line with pylint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829236/is-it-possible-to-ignore-one-single-specific-line-with-pylint)

Comment: Kind of, I didn't want to go with that solution tho since it would clutter up my art. Instead disabled W1401.

Comment: Would you mind edit your question to show the actual problem, and if indeed you found a solution then it'd be really helpful for others if you posted it as well.