# Disable pylint invalid module name warning only

Tags: python, pylint

I'd like to disable the pylint warning for `invalid-name` *only* for the module name.

The warning is: `Module name "some-module-name" doesn't conform to camelCase naming style`

I can disable the message by putting `# pylint: disable=invalid-name` at the top of the file, but this unfortunately disables *all* `invalid-name` errors, not just for the module.

Is there a way to disable the module invalid-name warning only?

Comment: I believe someone has answered your question already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829236/is-it-possible-to-ignore-one-single-specific-line-with-pylint

Answer (score 1):

While the question linked in the comments wasn't quite the same, it gave me an idea on how to solve it (perhaps in an unintended manner).

At the top of the file I place a disable & enable one after the other. This disables module-level invalid-name but re-enables so that other level checks are still active.

```py
# pylint: disable=invalid-name
# pylint: enable=invalid-name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `module-naming-style` option of pylint, setting it to *"any"* (rather than *"snake_case"* or *"cameCase"*), either via command-line:

```
$ pylint --module-naming-style=any src/
```

Or via `.pylintrc` file (if you have one):

```
$ pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc
$ grep "module-naming-style" .pylintrc
module-naming-style=any
```

For more details see: https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/1.7/user_guide/options.html#predefined-naming-styles