# What does "MEIPASS" stand for?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

PyInstaller sets the `sys._MEIPASS` attribute to let the application know where to find its bundled resources. Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7674790/119527).

I know what `_MEIPASS` does. *What does the name `_MEIPASS` mean? What does it stand for?*

- This was changed from an `MEIPASS2` environment variable in [version 2.0](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/4ed9c00ccbe70587709cdf1674c68d39c758cfbd/doc/CHANGES.rst#20-2012-08-08).
- Nothing in the [official documentation](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/master/doc/advanced-topics.rst) even alludes to the etymology of this variable.
- It appears to have been around since the beginning of PyInstaller.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472124/what-is-sys-meipass-in-python

Comment: @karthikr That doesn't begin to answer my question. I know what it **does**  but I want to what its name **means**.

Comment: Google is only turning up New York's Medicaid EHR Incentive Program Administrative Support Service. Maybe PyInstaller was originally developed by people working in New York in the health services industry.

Comment: @user2357112 I saw that too. I dismissed it as unrelated but I'm starting to wonder if you're right about its origin.

Comment: I can only hope that one day my cryptic variable names are similarly scrutinized.

Comment: @TemporalWolf A cryptic variable name is one thing. Public APIs (which this is) are another.

Comment: The MEIPASS name seems to be inherited from an older project, Gordon McMillan's Python installer (5b5, apparently). I don't know if the repository with all the commit logs for that was ever online.

Comment: My wild guess: the Japanese パス名, or *pasumei*, means "path name". The パス part can be the transliteration of either *path* or *pass*, so perhaps the original author (who seems to be Italian) thought it would be cute/humourous/reduce risk of collisions/whatever to swap the bits around so came up with **MEIPASS**.

Comment: It looks a bit what a german might write down if hearing `my_path` and has trouble with or doesn't know about the english „th“.

Answer (score 12):

According to [Codewarrior0](https://github.com/codewarrior0) (AKA: David Vierra) one of the pyinstaller developers:

> It comes from PyInstaller's ancestor, Mc**M**illan **E**nterprise **I**nstaller. Not sure about the PASS part, though.

([Source](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2610#issuecomment-301948362))

Comment: Can you link to a source for this quote? Is it from private correspondence or something? Your current link just goes to the guy's Github page.

Comment: @user2357112, I am an occasional contributor to pyinstaller, and I did in fact get an e-mail earlier with this information.  It was however Github's automated email from the issue tracker as the OP entered an Issue. :-)  See update.