# _build_ssl_context failing with PyInstaller

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert my .py file into a .exe.

The app works until it is in exe form, and I get the following errors, generated from
http requests coming from the textmagic library:

```
  File "main.py", line 88, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 20, in send_generics
  File "textmagic/rest/models/messages.py", line 91, in create
  File "textmagic/rest/models/base.py", line 214, in create_instance
  File "textmagic/rest/models/base.py", line 156, in request
  File "textmagic/rest/models/base.py", line 121, in make_tm_request
  File "textmagic/rest/models/base.py", line 86, in make_request
  File "httplib2/__init__.py", line 1558, in request
  File "httplib2/__init__.py", line 1077, in __init__
  File "httplib2/__init__.py", line 172, in _build_ssl_context
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've scavenged an identical issue with shotgun API on [this forum](https://community.shotgridsoftware.com/t/pyinstaller-created-executable-failing-in-build-ssl-context-shotgun-api3-lib-httplib2-python3-init-py/10339) and tweaked around *patrick-hubert-adsk's* response. This didn't work, but I may be doing something wrong here, particularly with the dst:

```
pyinstaller --add-data "`python3 -c 
'import httplib2; 
from httplib2 import certs;
import os; 
cacerts = certs.where(); 
print("%s:textmagic%s" % (cacerts, os.path.dirname(cacerts[len(httplib2.__path__[0]):])))'`" 
main.py
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the .exe has access to all of your packages?

Comment: Hi @Flow, I wouldn't be surprised if this is the issue considering the forum post I linked in the question. How could I ensure/validate that it has access to the packages, specifically to the certs that it doesn't seem able to find?

Comment: when you use pyinstaller does it generate a file called dist? @Daniel if so that is where all your packages should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend specifying a *few options on how to tell it to *find & add* -> `bundling the files needed in your exe`*.

Before looking at the options below, basically you can tell it the path via command line while running it

1. On a*dding the files to your `exe.`*; and bundling the files correctly into your exe.
2. This is important because it `unpacks them during install`, and using the `os.path.join` `os.path.join` etc.. as show in the samples below so it puts it in correct directory for the corresponding OS.

---

##### 1 [**Adding/Locating files**](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file):

To ensure the files and their paths are found correctly, please list arguments in command prompt to be used/found by pyinstaller; `--add-data "yourPath_to_file:yourPath_in_executable in directory"`

```
// fore .g. here favicon.png is located in directory of socketserver.py 
// which is later copied to the root directory of the executable (the `.` signifies root directory)
pyinstaller --add-data "favicon.png;." --onefile yourPythonProgam.py
```

##### 2 **Bundling files into your executables**

I am assuming you know how to edit the spec file, if not [here is a ref](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#:%7E:text=The%20spec%20file%20tells%20PyInstaller,contents%20of%20the%20spec%20file.).

Also if its a `--onedir` distribution, just pass a list of files (in TOC format) to the COLLECT, and they will show up in the distribution directory tree. The name in the (name, path, 'DATA') tuple can be a relative path name. Then, at runtime, you can use code like this to find the file:

> ```
> os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), relativename))
> ```

And in a `--onefile distribution`, your/data files are bundled in the executable, and when its run its then extracted at runtime into the work directory, that directory is best found by `os.environ['_MEIPASS2']`. So, `you can access those bundled files` through [ref: MEIPASS](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html):

> ```
> os.path.join(os.environ["_MEIPASS2"], relativename))
> ```

> ```
> from os import path
> bundle_dir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
> path_to_dat = path.join(bundle_dir, 'other-file.dat')
> ```

[What is MEIPASS/2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44013168/6085193)

---

- Ref for your `[Spec file][4]`

[image: PyInstaller does is to build a spec (specification) file myscript.spec. That file is stored in the --specpath directory, by default the current directory]

- Runtime to find your bundled exe file

[image: Pyinstaller MEIPASS]
A

- Adding files info:

[image: Ref to Pyinstaller adding files]

Comment: Never got a chance to thank you for this amazing response. Kudos, sir.

Comment: You are welcome Daniel :-)